# MySQL boolean match phrase does not work

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I use fulltext boolean match https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

**Works**

Matches `bear`, skip the rest:

```
+bear
```

**Works**

Matches `bear` OR `teddy`, skip the rest:

```
+(bear teddy)
```

**Doesn't work**

The expected behavior to me is `bear` OR `teddy` OR `me and my`, skip the rest. It does not work that way as I don't get the results.

```
+(bear teddy '"me and my"')
```

How can I get the expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the documentation. `me and my` just needs to be enclosed in double quotes, not single and double quotes as you have done. So your query should look something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST('+(bear teddy "me and my")' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (txt VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('here is a bear'), ('this is a teddy'),
('nothing to see here'), ('only me'), ('me and someone else'), ('oh my'),
('me and my children'), ('a teddy bear'), ('me and my teddy bear'),
('love me'), ('what about me and my life');
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT idx(txt);
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST('+(bear teddy "me and my")' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Output:

```
txt
here is a bear
this is a teddy
me and my children
a teddy bear
me and my bear
what about me and my life
```

If I change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST('+(bear teddy "me and all my")' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I lose the "me and my children" value, but keep "me and my teddy bear" as it contains "teddy" and "bear".

```
txt
a teddy bear
me and my teddy bear
here is a bear
this is a teddy
```

In none of the cases do values which only include one of the words "me", "and" or "my" get selected.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeaf7/1)

Comment: What your query does is that it also include words from "me and my" for example "love me" match and it should not. Instead it should match if it says "what about me and my life".

Comment: Hi Jens, are you sure? I am trying an almost identical query on my server (MySQL 5.6) and if I add another word into the phrase in double quotes I no longer get any matches, whereas from what you are saying I should get more.

Comment: @JensTörnell OK I've created an SQLFIDDLE and updated the answer. It definitely seems to be giving the result you wanted.